# Post data from form to php after Stripe payment success on the client

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have a online shop which sells products, the customers pay online via Stripe.
The customers arrive at the checkout page and pays using [Stripe elements](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-card-payments?platform=web&ui=elements).

The saving of data happens on the next page e.g. thankyou.php, customers only arrive their after the intent returns [succeeded](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-card-payments?platform=web&ui=elements#web-submit-payment).

The problem I am having is that, some user's may close the browser or navigate away before the `succeeded` response ever arrives from Stripe, in this instance the payment is taken but we never receive the order.

I am trying to avoid the webhooks method for a variety of reasons and feasability, are there any other techniques I could use? Would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: No, you should use the webhook to receive and verify the payment

Comment: that is exactly the perfect use case for webhooks. why should you reinvent the wheel and build a webhook replacement?

Comment: Fair enough I'm using connect with many websites so will have to look into how manage that